# Dynamically adding images to the Image Slideshow

Tags: jquery, file, dialog, slideshow

I'm new to javascript and trying make a image slide show using jquery plug-in with the help of this tutorial which is located here:

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/html5-canvas-slideshow-jquery/

What I need to do is to click the and call an open file dialog where i can make multiple selection of images and then add them into slideshow.

How could i manage to get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple files upload you should use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/).

Comment: Thanx for a quick reply, but my problem is I can't use php based plugin. Sorry for being a noob but its seems quite difficult as I dont have any server access to upload my php files there.

So if u could suggest me any other alternative would be nice.
Thankx

Comment: It's not platform dependent, you can use whatever language of your choice with it. However since you're uploading an image, I assume it should be uploaded to a server and hence you need a server language such as PHP or ASP.NET or Ruby or whatever.

Comment: I got ur point, Actually i'm trying to add files from a local computer and they gonna stay in local computer.

Is this possible to achieve through this plug-in?

Thanx